# Отследить изменение чекбокса, измененного через js

Tags: javascript, html, события

Нужно отследить изменение состояния чекбокса, в случае, если это состояние было изменено с помощью JS. Неожиданно для себя открыл, что при таком условии, событие `change` не эмитится

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('box');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
})
checkbox.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
  console.log("Состояние чекбокса изменнено")
})
```

```html
 <input id='box' type="checkbox">
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: как вариант, при изминении значения чекбокса, вызывать его событие `change` таким образом : `checkbox.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));`, ну или как в ответе Оптимуса, клик тоже должен сработать)

Comment: капец, тысяча просмотров - ни одного лайка за вопрос)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно переопределить сеттер для свойства `checked` при помощи [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

```
Object.defineProperty(checkbox, 'checked', {
    set: a => a != checkbox.checked && checkbox.click()
});
```

Вообще в общем случае получить доступ к прототипу html элемента нельзя, но тут получилось схитрить и дернуть `click` по условию, и вот результат

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('box');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
  console.log("Состояние чекбокса изменнено")
})

document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .forEach(cb => Object.defineProperty(cb, 'checked', {
      set: a => a != cb.checked && cb.click()
  }));
```

```html
<input id='box' type="checkbox">
<button id="btn" onclick="checkbox.checked = checkbox.checked">No change</button>
<button id="btn" onclick="checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked">change</button>
```

Comment: это равнозначно `if (a != checkbox.checked) checkbox.click()` при этом `a` это аргумент переданный в сеттер, т.е. то что вы присваиваете вот тут `checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked`

Answer (score -1):

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('box');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
  check(checkbox);
})

function check(el) {
  if (el.checked) {
    console.log("Флажок установлен");
  } else {
    console.log("Флажок не установлен");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id='box' type="checkbox">
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: Не, это не то. Потому что "отслеживание" идет в самом методе, который и изменяет состояние чекбокса. Минусы не мои

Comment: @Дмытрык через `change` вы точно не проверите. Это событие вызывается при потери фокуса checkbox, а у вас фокус вызывается по #btn

Comment: При потери фокуса вызывается `blur`. А при изменении состояния `change`. Вот только оказалось, что оно не срабатывет, если состояние изменить через JS

Comment: @Дмытрык ну так состояние изменения проверяется только тогда когда с элемента убран фокус, если вы измените форму и будете находиться в ней то `change` не вызовется

Comment: Автор хочет следить за изменениями, это предполагает что управляющий код, который меняет значение чекбоксов он менять не может