# Делегирование событий JavaScript и dispatchEvent

Tags: javascript

Имеются select'ы, которые вставляются в документ динамический, их изменения обрабатывают так:

```
document.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    if(event.target.contains('select-class')) { ... }
});
```

Иногда меняю их значения через value: "select.value = value;". Когда меняю значение, то событие не вызывается. Пробовал вот так:

```
select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
...
document.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Ничего из этого не сработало. Как я могу это решить?

Comment: смотрите тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/977111/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вторым аргументом передается обект с свойствами например разрешить всплытие

```
dispatchEvent(new Event('change',{bubbles:true}))
```

но в твоем примере с document.dispatch все должно работать и без всплытия там пропушена скобка

мне кажется ты не правильно понял темы делегирования и слушателей вообше есть не только всплытие  но и погружение если у тебя слушатель на элементе а событие срабатывает  на родителе тебе надо ловить на погужении и обратная логика если переставить местами то на всплытии.Какие параметры за это отвечають можно глянуть в любой документации.Что касается сгенерированных событий то есть не пользовательских они по дефолту не умеют всплывать про пагружение не помню так что если слушатель на документе а событие генерируется на элементе то надо обязательно указать {bubbles:true} что бы оно всплыло до документа

Comment: ```document.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {target: select}));``` так не получается. Как я понял там можно только определенные параметры передать https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю насколько это правильно, но для меня это работает

```
// при изменении селекта
let changeEvent = new Event('change');
changeEvent._target = control;
document.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);

// в обработчике
document.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    const target = event._target || event.target;
    if(target.contains('select-class')) { ... }
});
```