# Как отследить любые изменения значение input? Оно меняется в том числе программно

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $('input[name="inc-dec"]').on('change', function (e) {
    console.log($(this).val());
  })
```

Как отследить любые изменения инпута, если оно меняется динамически? Данный код позволяет лишь отследить ввод и нажатие Enter

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/977111/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-js

Comment: Если без отслеживания: программно изменили значение, затем вызвать  `$('input[name="inc-dec"]').trigger('change');`  [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16250542/6752984)

Answer (score -1):

Просто так - никак.
Вызывать нужно функцию в том месте, где "что-то" меняет значение поля.
Либо проксировать сеттер value и метод setAttribute.

```
const elem = document.querySelector('input[name="inc-dec"]');

const descriptorProp = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value');
const descriptorAttr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, 'setAttribute');

const onChange = (value) => {
   console.log(value);
};


Object.defineProperties(elem, {
  value: {
    get: descriptorProp.get,
    set(value) {
        onChange(value);
      descriptorProp.set.call(this, value);
    },
  },
  setAttribute: {
    value(attr, value) {
      if (attr === 'value') {
        onChange(value);
      }
      descriptorAttr.value.call(this, attr, value);
    },
  }
});


elem.addEventListener('input', () => onChange(elem.value));
```

Answer (score -1):

> Как отследить любые изменения инпута, **если оно меняется динамически?**

> `onchange` позволяет лишь отследить ввод **и нажатие Enter**

т.е. надо отследить изменения содержимого "на лету" - до нажатия `enter`, верно?

для этих целей есть `oninput`

```js
let q = document.getElementById("x");
```

```css
#x{background: pink}
```

```html
<input oninput='q.innerHTML=this.value;' placeholder="развлейкайтесь">
<div id='x'>123</div>
<input type='range' min='0' max='359' 
oninput='q.style="filter: hue-rotate(" + this.value + "deg);";'>
```