# Событие change не срабатывает при изменении значения с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При загрузке страницы я устанавливаю значения инпута из куков:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#user-id").val(getCookie("user_id"));
 });
```

Но при таком раскладе событие change попросту не срабатывает:

```
$("#user-id").change(function() {
    console.log("Triggered");
}
```

Как можно это пофиксить? Используется jquery 3.3.1 версии.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отследить изменение чекбокса, измененного через js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/977111/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-js)

Comment: А как связана установка значения атрибута и работа события?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну событие тригерит при изменении этого интупа, мы его по сути так же изменяет с помощью js а не пользователя.

Comment: Событие работает при изменении значении в инпуте, а не значения атрибута

Comment: @Дмытрык не совсем то что нужно мне посоветовали вызвать этот тригер в ручную по типу `$("#user-id").val(getCookie("user_id")).trigger("change");`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский теперь буду знать, извините)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В jQuery есть метод [.trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/), запускающий события:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#user-id").val(111).trigger("change");
});

$("#user-id").change(function() {
  console.log("Triggered");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="user-id">
```

---

Без trigger, можно просто вызвать функцию и там, и там:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#user-id").val(111);
  myFunction();
});

$("#user-id").change(myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  console.log("Triggered");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="user-id">
```

Answer (score 1):

Событие работает на самом деле. Но, возможно, вам нужно событие `input` ?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#user-id").val(1111);
});


$("#user-id").on('input', function() {
    console.log("Triggered");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="user-id" value="" />
```

---

Если я что-то вообще правильно понял :D

Comment: на самом деле помог более простой метод - вызов этого триггера в ручную.

`$("#user-id").val(getCookie("user_id")).trigger("change");`

Comment: @HedgeHog хорошо :-)